# How do I trigger single & doubleclick on jvectormap

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

How do I combine single & double click into `onRegionClick` using jvectormap.

I want to load different link between single & double click event.

```
onRegionClick:function(event, code){            
    if(single) {
      $('#info').load("/single?q="+code);
    } else {
      $('#info').load("/double?q="+code);
    }
  },
```